# Dart/Flutter List.isNotEmpty() is incorrect?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to access a list, but only if it isn't empty. After receiving some odd pathing, I discovered that the List.isNotEmpty is returning a length of 0, and it is not empty. Unless, of course, what I consider "empty" is in the wrong mindset?

Here's the test I ran, where I created an "empty" list. Then, I tested to see what came back when I tested isNotEmpty.

```
List<String> myKeywords = [];
if(myKeywords.isNotEmpty){
  print("Keywords is not empty..?");
  print("Keywords length = ${myKeywords.length}");
  print("Keyword: \"${myKeywords.first}\"");
}
```

// output

```
Keywords is not empty..?
Keywords length = 0
// Error: Bad state: No element
```

This doesn't work the same way with strings:

```
String myString = "";
if(myString.isNotEmpty){
  print("myString is not empty..?");
  print("myString length = ${myString.length}");
}
else{
  print("myString is empty");
}
```

Output:

```
myString is empty
```

Looking at documentation, List.isNotEmpty states the following:

```
Whether this collection has at least one element.
May be computed by checking if iterator.moveNext() returns true.
Example:
final numbers =  {1, 2, 3};
print(numbers.isNotEmpty); // true;
print(numbers.iterator.moveNext()); // true
```

Can someone explain this to me? Or, perhaps this is a bug?

Android Studio
Dart SDK Version - 2.19.4 (Stable)
Flutter Version - 3.7.7 (Stable)

Thank you!

Comment: Is this your exact code?  If not, please provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example.  I can't reproduce any such problem with JIT or AOT modes with Dart 2.19.4, and it's very unlikely that `List.isNotEmpty`'s would misbehave so; there would be many automated tests that would fail.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for testing this on my behalf! Unfortunately, this was my exact code. I created a function that would return a Widget, depending on the list values. However, when having issues, I then changed it to a void function for testing. The new, void, function had everything commented out except the lines shown above. The results are what you see here. My issue ended up resolving itself without any intervention though... which is just as scary as this not working in the first place. I can't even reproduce the issue now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually working as expected. Try debugging your program, because the output stated above is incorrect

*Make sure you have not added any element between `isNotEmpty` and initialization.*

The output of the following code would be:

```dart
List<String> myKeywords = [];
if (myKeywords.isNotEmpty){
  print("Keywords is not empty..?");
  print("Keywords length = ${myKeywords.length}");
  print("Keyword: \"${myKeywords.first}\"");
} else {
  print("Keywords is empty");
}
```

The following code should return `Keywords is empty`.

Check this [DartPad](https://www.dartpad.dev/?id=e53ffc808a77fc5eac3e7fa8239ccf22) link.

Comment: This link explain how share your Dart Pad : https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/wiki/Sharing-Guide

Comment: I was wondering how that was done, thanks for the link!

Comment: I am marking this as correct. The issue is still unknown, but has resolved itself after closing and reopening the Android Studio IDE. I have changed nothing, and it is working as expected now. The issue may lie in the fact that I built a new PC with 3 hard drives. The first hard drive has the OS only, the second hard drive is software only, and the 3rd drive contains only files (including SDK's). It's possible there were some linking issues with the 3rd drive? Unsure.